# Output Data from Json using PHP (Arrays)

Tags: php, arrays, json

This is my json Output. i want to echo 'resolution' only. How is that possible?

```
Array
(
[uploader] => CoversDamian
[formats] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [preference] => -50
                [resolution] => 720p
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [preference] => -100
                [resolution] => 1080p
            )
    )          
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myarray = Array
(
[uploader] => CoversDamian
[formats] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [preference] => -50
                [resolution] => 720p
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [preference] => -100
                [resolution] => 1080p
            )
    )          
)
```

**echo $myarray["formats"][1]["resolution"];**

if you have more array in `formats` key then you can use `foreach` loop based on `formats` key. Becuase you want to print all resolution under the `formats` key. 
So

```
foreach($myarray["formats"] as $key => $value){
    echo $value["resolution"]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: i want to echo all the resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you want to echo all resolutions you need a loop like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array["formats"]); $i++){
 echo $array["formats"][$i]["resolution"];
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Got the values but with an error : undefined index: resolution .. what to do with that?

Comment: Code is too big to paste here. I pasted the same sample code here. @albert

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the json is in object notation, stored as `$json` you can loop through the 'formats' as follows :

```
foreach($json->formats as $key=>$value) {
   echo $value->resolution . "\n";
}
```

If it is not in object notation, you can loop through the sub-keys in the array (assuming it is store in the variable `$json`) as follows :

```
foreach($json['formats'] as $key=>$value) {
   echo $value['resolution'] . "\n";
}
```

Notice the subtle difference in the way you can access sub-keys/elements in an object vs in an array.

Comment: @Aamir Try wrapping  `if(isset($value['resolution'])) { echo $value['resolution'] . "\n"; }` or `if(isset($value->resolution)) { echo $value->resolution . "\n"; }` .  Sounds like one of the elements doesn't contain a `resolution` key

Comment: Thanks Man! Got it.

Comment: One more question if i want to put the ['url'] under the resolutions that we got , then what should i do?

Comment: `['url']` is not part of the original question or contained in the format.  You can added any data however you like.   `.` is concatenate in php.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
'uploader' => 'CoversDamian',
'formats' => array
    (
        0 => array
            (
                'preference' => '-50',
                'resolution' => '720p'
            ),
        1 => array
            (
                'preference' => -'100',
                'resolution' => '1080p'
            )
    )          
);

foreach ($arr['formats'] as $key=>$val) {
  echo   $val['resolution'];
}
```